# EaselJS: add child with mousedown triggered

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

The basic functionality I'm going for is...

Tap (`mousedown`) on the stage to create and add a child at that location.

*EDIT: I'm also trying to solve for multitouch, so multiple balls can be created at the same time.

As you hold down you can drag (pressmove) that child around and it grows (using regX/regY/scaleX/scaleY) until you release (`pressup`), at which point it falls (using a tick cycle).

I have everything sort of working, but I've hit a snag wherein I can't add a child and have it immediately register `mousedown` without releasing and pressing again.

Is there a way to manually trigger `mousedown` after adding, or some other workaround that makes more sense? `dispatchEvent` doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my stage event listener and touch bits:

```
            stage.enableMouseOver(10);
            createjs.Touch.enable(stage, false, false);
            stage.preventSelection = false;
            stage.addEventListener("stagemousedown", spawnsnowball);
```

And here are my functions. The spawnsnowball one includes `displayObject` event listeners verging on desperate, but the only way I've been able to get the pressmove and pressup working is to click on the same snowball again. `releasesnowball` right now just releases all instances of them (using a `'stagemouseup'` listener), but if I can get it triggering off of `pressup` then I'll rewrite it to target just the event target.

```
        function spawnsnowball(evt){
            var ball = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("snowball"));
            ball.crossOrigin="Anonymous";
            ball.name="ball";
            ball.scaleX = 0.5;
            ball.scaleY = ball.scaleX;
            ball.regX = ball.image.width/2;
            ball.regY = ball.image.height/2;
            ball.x = evt.stageX;
            ball.y = evt.stageY;

            ball.type = balltype;

            ball.holding = 1;
            ball.velX = 0;
            ball.velY = 0;
            ball.addEventListener("pressup",releasesnowball);
            ball.addEventListener("pressmove",dragsnowball);
            ball.onPress = function(mouseEvent) {};
            stage.addChild(ball);
            ball.dispatchEvent("mousedown");
            ball.dispatchEvent("pressdown");

        }

        function dragsnowball(evt){
            evt.target.x = evt.stageX;
            evt.target.y = evt.stageY;
        }

        function releasesnowball(evt){
            for(var i=0;i<stage.getNumChildren();i++){
                var shape = stage.getChildAt(i);
                if(shape.type == balltype){
                    if(shape.holding){
                        shape.holding = 0;
                        var dX = shape.x - shape.oldX;
                        var dY = shape.y - shape.oldY;
                        if(Math.abs(dY)>8)
                            dY = 8*dY/Math.abs(dY);
                        if(Math.abs(dX)>3)
                            dX = 3*dX/Math.abs(dX);

                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pressmove` event is special because it basically stores off the target of the last `mousedown` event, and then remembers it for `pressmove` and `pressup` events.

This means you can't really fake the event by forcing mouse events. Dispatching a mouse event from the target will not do the trick.

Instead, consider just handling the initial drag manually. You already know what you want to be the target of the pressmove, so you can listen for the `stagemousemove` event, and handle it yourself:

```
// Listen to the stagemousemove and manually call the event.
  var initialDrag = stage.on("stagemousemove", function(event) {
    event.target = ball; // Re-target the event so your other method works fine.
    dragsnowball(event);
  });

// When done, remove the move listener.
// The off() method supports a "once" parameter so you don't have to unsubscribe that listener.
  stage.on("stagemouseup", function(event) {
    stage.off("stagemousemove", initialDrag);
  }, null, true); // Fires one time
```

Here is a quick sample using your code as the base: http://jsfiddle.net/3qhmur82/

I also added some comments in the demo which might be useful.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome thank you! It seems to work well for a single one, but I'm trying to solve for multi-touch (I had a similar solution that just went and found all "balltype" children and released them all on `stagemouseup`).

That said, some really great insights on what I'm spinning wheels on. Thank you again!